# Gantt chart is not plotting data properly in fusion charts

Tags: javascript, charts, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion charts library and I am facing issue with Gantt chart as data is plotting correctly though I verified all data being passed correctly as per documentation.

It takes long width for 1 hour which `13:00` to `14:00` in my chart. Please suggest something to solve this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhdw66ub/9/)

Comment: did you solve this problem?